# Excel VBA add data validation backround color two separate cells

Tags: excel, vba

If user changes data validation at the sheet `mySheet.Cells(row, 3).`

[image: Snippet from mySheet]

Requirement is that the program updates same background-color immediately different sheet like `mySecondSheet.Cells(row, 2).`

[image]

What I have to add in my code?

```
Public Function addDataValidation(row As Long)

Dim optionList(2) As String

optionList(0) = "1"
optionList(1) = "2"
optionList(2) = "3"

    With mySheet.Cells(row, 3).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(optionList, ",")
    End With

   With mySheet.Cells(row, 3).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=1")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, 3).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=2")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, 3).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=3")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, 3)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Value = optionList(0)
    End With

End Function
```